# Buck-Boost converter not working right when fed by dynamo

Tags: buck-boost

So my plan is to charge a powerbank with a bicycle dynamo. I have got it to work with a full bridge rectifier and a linear regulator, it just isn't very effective. I used the following circuit:

[image: schematic diagram]

(The hatched box is the circuit that comes with the powerbank).

After some research I found that using a buck-boost converter is way more effective. So I ordered the following from AliExpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Boost-Buck-DC-DC-adjustable-step-up-down-Converter-XL6009-Module-Solar-Voltage/32661520979.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.36774c4dvUq5VL

I connected it to my DC voltage generator to set the voltage to approximately 4.5 V, since that's what the power bank would need. Until here it all worked fine.

Then I connected it to my circuit instead of the linear regulator. When I started spinning the dynamo, the output-voltage of the buck-boost converter would rise quickly to 20 or 25 V (probably even more, didn't want to try that though, in fear of breaking it) with only 3 to 4 V input. I also tried it without the capacitor (1500 μF), hoping that would solve the issue, which it unfortunately didn't.

I know there are different types of buck-boost converters and I might have picked the wrong kind...
Could someone please help me to get this working?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: The linear regulator I used is a L7805CV, which has an output voltage of 5V.

Here the schematics of the circuit I used with the buck-boost converter:
[image]

The Capacitor should be big enough. I measured it with an old oscilloscope and it looked fine as far as I can tell (by that I mean it was a more or less smooth line).

Comment: Did you measure the output of the linear regulator?

Comment: When testing the buck boost, did you do it under load? Add a load resistor or some leds with resistor you wouldn't worry about blowing.

Comment: I think you're basically screwed. The [XL6009](https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300) controller on that module is fundamentally a boost converter. The only way to get it to buck is in a SEPIC configuration, and I don't see how the components on the module would achieve that.

Comment: @DaveTweed So what do you suggest I should do? Get another buck-boost converter? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @winny nothing about this is related to usb handshakes. Nothing.

Comment: @Passerby Calm down!

Comment: @Passerby I tested it again under load (with the actual powerbank) and it stoped doing that thing where the voltage rises that high. However, the output voltage of the buck boost is almost the same as the input voltage (doesn't matter how high that is). So i assume my buck boost is somehow broken. Do you have any recomendations on what else i could use for this purpose or which buck boost i should get?

Answer (score 1):

The bicycle "dynamo" you have shown in the schematic is an alternator. (A [dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo) is an electrical generator that creates direct current using a commutator.) This means that the voltage on the input to your buck-boost converter will be seeing half-wave rectified AC unless the capacitor is big enough to maintain voltage during the valleys. (Why is there no C value shown on the schematic?)

If you edit your question to show an accurate schematic of your setup we may be able to help further.

Comment: The Dynamo is a AC generator then. That's why I used the full bridge rectifier

Comment: OP includes the capacitor value in the question text.

Comment: Sorry, if it was there I missed it.